# How to run Rails web app as a desktop or offline app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a rails web application running on the Heroku server, and I need this application to run using a local server, or running offline. I was trying rack-offline but I wonder if there's a simplest way, like a program to use the local server without applying commands in the terminal.

This is for production purpose, the app is already running and they want it to work without an internet connection. The data can be just for offline usage.

I will appreciate any help. thank you.

Comment: Do you need it for development purposes? If for production purposes - what about the data? Should be shared between offline and online usage?

Comment: Thank you, The data can be offline, I don't need it to share it online. And it's also for production purpose.

Comment: So you just want a local instance of your application, for using on one machine only?

Comment: You could run it on a server which is accessible to your network but not the internet perhaps?

Comment: Yes, just a local instance, I don't need anything from the internet.

Comment: What is the general purpose of the app?  Will it evolve over time? Will new features ever be required? What database(s) are used?

Comment: The crux of this question seems how to be how to run a rails app without a terminal... it already has a built in offline server: `rails server`

Answer (score 3):

If you want your application to work offline, and have no connection to the outside world, then you can use [ruby-packer](https://github.com/pmq20/ruby-packer) or similar to create a binary of your application. This option avoids having end users playing with the terminal.

Think of the implications for your use case though:

- If multiple people use this application, does the data need to be synced between them all or can they all have a local copy that's different? If so then it needs a data connection.
- Do you need to maintain the hosted version, and does it need to talk to any of the local copies ever?

Comment: If the application relies on a database as many rails apps do, how do you deal with setting up/seeding the database?  There are many things that need consideration. Have you even used this successfully with a basic rails app?

Comment: I have used it yeah, it heavily depends on your application target, but I'm suggesting it based on the information provided (that the application can work offline, without any data connection), and just added some things to think about so he doesn't try and force his application to work with this if it's not suitable.